# Android: Set an image to an ImageButton in a separate thread (background)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, background, intentservice

I am using a ViewPager and it's horizontal screen sliding feature to swipe between Fragments that each contain an image.

However, the pages are very slow to load since I am currently loading these images on the UI Thread. Here's how I am currently doing it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pictures);

    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture_one);
}
```

**I'd like to simply load my image (R.drawable.picture_one) to the ImageButton on a background/separate thread.**

I looked at Cursor, but it seems to only be used for database queries.

How would I do this? Thank you!

Comment: it doesnt matter if the image is in your resource. it slow because of the size of your picture maybe

Comment: Use a async task or if you want use the android universal image loader in this link [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Thanks bean_droid! I will check that link out